# Memory requirements for hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, memory-management, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh

I am a starter in hadoop. How do I know how much RAM does my hadoop cluster have and how much RAM is my application using? I am using CDH 5.3 version but I would prefer knowing it in general for hadoop clusters.

Comment: What application RAM usage you mean? There are lots of services in Hadoop ecosystem. Do you mean overall RAM usage?

Comment: Let us say there are 3 applications running MR1, MR2, Hive3. How do I know how much can my cluster offer? How much does MR1, MR2 use? How much does Hive3 use?

Comment: Is there a way to set prioroities and assign preferences in memory usage? say 30% reserved for MR1?

Comment: If you use YARN as a MR engine you could config it to run different applications on it. YARN is basically is a resource allocation system. I haven't used it myself, so try to dig into this direction

Comment: All the details are available in Yarn resource manager page.